# Is it ok to use DialogFragment in fullscreen to simulate a new activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, dialog

I am trying to know if it is ok to manage the "navigation" of my app with DialogFragments all the time, putting them in fullscreen as if they were Activities.
Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this. You can also do the opposite (using activities as dialogs, which is just weird).

The only real reason to do so is to reuse a fragment both as a dialog and as a full screen view, perhaps for different screen sizes, etc.

> You might have a UI design in which you want a piece of the UI to appear as a dialog in some situations, but as a full screen or embedded fragment in others (perhaps depending on whether the device is a large screen or small screen). The DialogFragment class offers you this flexibility because it can still behave as an embeddable Fragment.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#FullscreenDialog

Doing this in general for no real reason would be an odd practice

Comment: Ok then, I guess I will use new activities. My question comes because of [link](http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/dialogs.html#dialogs-full-screen-dialogs), where they talk about full-screen Dialogs. Maybe they're talking about the "design concept" and it doesn't have to be DialogFragments?